# MapOverlays not updating

Tags: android, google-maps

I have the following code, which draws a route on the map. It have to do the following steps:

- Check if have a route drawn;

  - If has, removes from the map;
- Get the route from Google;
- Draw the route on the map;
- Update the map.

When the code it's executed in the first time, it draw's fine. But after the first execution, it keeps removing the route overlay, insert the new route overlay into the MapOverlays but the map doesn't draws the route on the interface.

I don't know how to fix this. Someone could help me?

Thanks in advance.

```
public void drawRoute(Location from, double toLat, double toLon) {
    String url = RoadProvider.getUrl(from.getLatitude(), from.getLongitude(), toLat, toLon);
    Log.i("rotaUrl", url);

    JSONGet routeHttpObj = new JSONGet(mContext, url) {
        @Override
        protected void jsonHandler(JSONObject routeJsonObj) {
            Log.i("Rota", "Rota recebida...");

            try {
                // Qual o status da requisição da rota?
                String status = routeJsonObj.getString("status").toString();

                // O webservice conseguiu traçar uma rota?
                if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("OK")) {
                    Log.i("Rota", "Ok");

                    Log.i("overlay", mapOverlays.toString());
                    Log.i("overlay", mapOverlays.size()+"");
                    // Remove a rota, caso exista
                    if (mapOverlays.size() == 3) {
                        mapOverlays.remove(2);
                    }
                    Log.i("overlay", mapOverlays.size()+"");

                    // Extração da polyline codificada
                    String polyline = routeJsonObj.getJSONArray("routes").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("overview_polyline").getString("points");

                    // Decodificação da polyline para um array de GeoPoints
                    ArrayList<GeoPoint> route = RoadProvider.decodePolyline(polyline);

                    // Instanciamento do objeto da rota
                    RoadOverlay routeOverlay = new RoadOverlay(route);

                    // Pega a lista de overlays e adiciona a rota ao mapview
                    mapOverlays.add(routeOverlay);

                    // Reseta o mapa
                    mapView.postInvalidate();

                    Log.i("overlay", mapOverlays.size()+"");
                    Log.i("overlay", mapOverlays.toString());

                    // Pega os passos da rota
                    /*JSONArray routeSteps = routeJsonObj.getJSONArray("routes").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("legs").getJSONArray("steps");

                    // Percorre os passos da rota e insere nos vetores, para guiar o motorista
                    for (int i=0; i<routeSteps.length(); i++) {
                        // O objeto do passo no indice i
                        JSONObject stepObj = routeSteps.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Cria o array dos pontos
                        GeoPoint[] arrPoints = new GeoPoint[2];

                        // Insere a latitude e longitude no array
                        //arrPoints[0] = stepObj.getJSONObject(name)

                        // Insere o array na lista
                        routePoints.add(arrPoints);
                        // routeInstructions
                    }*/

                    // Copia os pontos para referencia futura
                    routePoints = (ArrayList<GeoPoint>) route.clone();
                } else {
                    // Qual o erro?
                    if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("NOT_FOUND")) {

                    } else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("ZERO_RESULTS")) {

                    } else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("MAX_WAYPOINTS_EXCEEDED")) {

                    } else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("INVALID_REQUEST")) {

                    } else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("OVER_QUERY_LIMIT") || status.equalsIgnoreCase("REQUEST_DENIED")) {

                    } else {

                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    // Desabilita a exibição do loading
    routeHttpObj.setDisplayDialog(false);

    // Executa a requisição
    routeHttpObj.execute();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the suggestion here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5730710/1337412

> When you add or remove an overlayItem you need to call populate() in
>   your MarkerOverlay class.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's one thing I didn't tried, but I'm not using ItemizedOverlay to the routes, so how can I call this method?

Comment: I´ve crated the method populateNow() on my ItemizedOverlay class, and I'm calling it after delete the Overlay and adding new one, but doesn't update neither...